# load just english web page with jsoup (verify language before loading)

Tags: jsoup

I want to download a list of web pages (more than 1 million web pages) and i want to download only English web page 
How can i do to specify a language ? I tried this

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element taglang = htmlDoc.select("html").first();
System.out.println(taglang.text());
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can't know the language of a served page prior downloading it. The only thing you can do is to request the server respond in a preferred language. this can be done using the [Accept-Langage](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) http header. In Jsoup you can do this:

```
Jsoup.connection(url).header("Accept-Language", "en");
```

There is no guarantee that the server will acknowledge this header. Checking the content language after download may be done with the [Content-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.12) header. Again, the server may not send this header or it may be wrong.